# Split random linked list then order them

Tags: c, algorithm, merge, linked-list, mergesort

I am currently trying to split a linked list into two then order those two lists. After doing that I am trying to merge them into one big list again.

Comment: How about showing some code and an example?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do you should always check "unknown" pointers to see if they are NULL and then make a decision based on that.

so in your case you can add in somthing like:

```
if (temp == NULL)
{
    // End of list action
}
else
{
    left_list -> tail = temp -> prev; etc...
}
```

You really should do this for all places where you are about to assign a value from a pointer. If you include this sort of checking into your design you will be forced to handle the cases for empty / end of lists and the design will be easier to manage and easier to decode.

Comment: Okay so I should put that infront of my split function?

Comment: Yes, that is one option. I.e. "if there is only 1 element do not do a split" :)

Comment: Okay that makes sense. do i even want to get my list down to one? or should i get it to two and then sort?

Comment: The usual way is to end up with a single element in a list which is "sorted" by the fact that there is only one element. Then you start merge-sorting the lists together. But I don't suppose that is essential. I would try to get the list down to one element for "correctness" and for your own personal satisfaction : )

Comment: Okay so once I get it all down to one element it should work correctly?

Comment: haha, well, that is the plan :) I can't say for sure, these things are hard to work through only in your head and I can only see part of the code. First you need to get past your seg-faults and get the code to run. Then we see what result you get (with some debug). If things are not working as planned then we can at least see what happened and take it from there.